# 301 Redirect an URL In .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

This is the URL in question

```
/?L=inkspot.topic&id=82255&page=22
```

I need to redirect it to the home page of the website.

Obviously, the id and page are variables. I'm not good at .htaccess 301 redirects so your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
//301 Redirect 
RedirectMatch  /?L=inkspot.topic&id=(.+)&page=(.+) http://www.google.ca/$1/$2  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error! But thank you so much for your speedy answer AndroidUser!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, it seems that carrying over parameters to the redirect is done as follows. I've never needed to rewrite in this fashion, so this is new to me...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^L=inkspot.topic$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html/%1/%2/%3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry Gordon, this didn't throw a server error but didn't do anything to the page, it just remained.

Comment: Hi again Gordon and thank you for trying. It still remained on the same page. I'm sorry for your troubles.

Comment: That's okay. I've had my trials with .htaccess rules in the past too. It's worth the effort when it finally works.

Comment: It's a site powered by phpizabi, and i've had some pretty intelligent people try and help write the lines for a few 301s I needed for this site and for some reason it takes quite some time to get it. Even the 301 or redirect generators out there never get it...

Comment: I did some research yesterday and found that doing redirects with params is done a little differently than the way I'm used to. I'm experienced with translating clean URL's *into* a list of params. I edited my answer to suit your problem space.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I hate to say that didn't work either. It's not your fault though, I swear it's the software the site is powered by, namely phpizabi. It's been the hardest site ever to use redirects and so forth...is there anything I can give you that will help? I can tell you the page still loads, no errors...